# Jinja Invalid Filter, filter is built in

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2

I have read through the Jinja documentation and am using the `truncate` filter. I have used it exactly as defined in the documentation.

From the docs:

> truncate(s, length=255, killwords=False, end=’…’, leeway=None) 
>   Return a truncated copy of the string. The length is specified with the first
>   parameter which defaults to 255. If the second parameter is true the
>   filter will cut the text at length. Otherwise it will discard the last
>   word. If the text was in fact truncated it will append an ellipsis
>   sign ("..."). If you want a different ellipsis sign than "..." you can
>   specify it using the third parameter. Strings that only exceed the
>   length by the tolerance margin given in the fourth parameter will not
>   be truncated.

Here is my code:

```
{% if post.replies.all %}
<ul class="accordion" data-accordion data-multi-Expand="true" data-allow-all-closed="true">
{% for reply in post.replies.all %}
        <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion>
            <a href="#" class="accordion-title">{{reply.by}}: {{reply.content|truncate(14)}}</a>
            <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
                <img src="{{ reply.by.profile.img_url }}" class="thumbnail" width="50" height="50">
                <p>{{ reply.content }}</p>
            </div>
        </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

I get the following traceback after testing:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure Django is treating the template as Jinja? You might get that error if it was treated as Django template language. In Jinja, I would expect you to call `post.replies.all()`.

Comment: I'm not certain. I checked my version to make sure I had Jinja2 and I in fact only had 1.2. I upgraded to Jinja2 to no avail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are quite simply **not using Jinja**. You are using the Django template language.

Django's built-in filters are documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/); the filter that truncate strings is called [`truncatechars`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars). You also need to use Django syntax to pass the parameters to the filter.

```
{{reply.content|truncatechars:14}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How can I switch and use jinja instead? I have 'jinja2' listed in my `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`, but I guess that's simply not working.

Comment: You need to change the template backend - see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/#support-for-template-engines). I really recommend not doing this though unless you have a very good reason; apart from anything else, as Alasdair pointed out, some other parts of your template are already based on Django syntax not Jinja.

Comment: Thank you for your concise answers. I have one question though, why would it still be using jinja if I have jinja listed in my `INSTALLED_APPS` setting?

Comment: Assuming you mean "why would it still be using Django template language":  why wouldn't it? If you haven't changed the template backend, you haven't done anything to tell it to use Jinja.